# Performing an actual redirect to 404 page

Tags: redirects, 404

I'm having no trouble displaying a 404 page when using `{redirect="404"}`, but is there any way to *actually* redirect to my 404 page? ie. changing the url to /404 ?

I've seen [Ryan's blog post](http://joviawebstudio.com/index_ee.php/blog/guide_to_404_pages_with_expressionengine/), but he uses PHP to do it. Should I just write a simple plugin to do that?

**Update:**
I've created a plugin for this behavior.
https://github.com/jazonv/fourofour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You just need to use the native [redirect tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#redirect):

```
{redirect='site/404'}
```

That will redirect to the template_group/template specified.  :)

Comment: Ah, thanks, but the headers on that page are '302 Found', not 404.

Comment: Technically this answers my question though.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Yes I guess it would never be a 404 if it redirects to a found page. You could always directly insert the header on the page: <?php
$this->EE->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); but I see you've already gone one better and wrapped this up into a handy plugin. :) Nicely done.